# Ajax Success callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

When the user clicks on comment icon, the following must happen: (a) invoke the AJAX function called SearchData(urlVal, paramVal, callback), residing in customscript.js file. Pass parameters that point to MovieReview action method inside Movie Controller, the value of query should be movie Id. (b) create a function called successMovieReviewHandler, which is your AJAX on success callback function that receives the results of your AJAX call. Inside this, function check for errors and data validity. Assign Title to your modal title, PartialView to modal body and invoke your modal with these settings keyboard: false, and backdrop: "static"?

This is my code in my Movie Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public JsonResult MovieReview(Guid? query)
        {
            var m = db.Movies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == query);
            if (m != null)
            {
                MovieReview review = new MovieReview();
                review.Id = (Guid)query;

                var viewContent = ConvertViewToString("_MovieReview", review);
                //var viewContent = ConvertViewToString("_ReviewModal", review);
                return Json(new { PartialView = viewContent, Title = m.Title, Success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json("",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }

        [ChildActionOnly]
        private string ConvertViewToString(string viewName, object model)
        {
            ViewData.Model = model;

            using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                var vResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);

                var vContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, vResult.View, ViewData, (new TempDataDictionary()), writer);

                vResult.View.Render(vContext, writer);

                return writer.ToString();
            }
        }
```

This is the Ajax Function:

```
function SearchData(urlVal, paramVal, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: urlVal,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        data: { query: paramVal },
        success: callback,
        error: function (data) {
            // data contains the value returned by the server

            console.log("Error : " + data);
        }
    });
}
```

Please help me to create the ajax success callback function!

Comment: This is quite vague. What specifically about the callback do you need help with?

Comment: Having trouble creating the Ajax callback in the Index View. Need to pass data from the controller to a partial view to in order to use a popup edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **callback** ajax function got on is **param** **DATA** is the **OBJECT** return of you server page.

This server page ***must return an object json*** and must send a **header content as text/json,** you can add too **status code** if you wanted.

```
 function callback(data){
     console.log(data);
     alert(data);
 }
```